# how to remove post "categories" from showing up on the the hamburger/toggle menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, categories, posts

I'm trying to find some CSS to help me stop having "**post page categories**" from showing up on the hamburger/toggle menu on wordpress. For example here, i'm making [www.byjgk.com](http://www.byjgk.com) and when the hamburger menu is clicked, and gives me the dropdown, besides the normal menu items, i keep seeing "uncategorized" below the normal menu as additional menu items (or, if I add any categories to a post, those categories below the menu items.) It's driving me crazy and i can't figure out how to stop it! Please help, thanks!

FYI - I tried the follow two bits of CSS, but they didn't seem to do anything:

```
.hamburger-panel .category-links { display: none; }
.hamburger-panel .panel-body-contents > hr { display: none; }
```

And:

```
.menu-panel li a.widget-link[href="/categories"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the same in theme settings and mobile menu if you want to do it with CSS try this code.

```
.widget_categories
{
 display:none!important;
}
```